# Как заполнить kendocombox из метода в контроллере используя JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo

Есть проект на mvc4 на форме динамически формируется таблица (заранее кол-во строк не известно), в одной из столбцов таблицы необходимы combobox, которые получают значения из метода в контроллере. Пробую следующим образом, но метод не вызывается

```
$(".tableE tbody tr td input[id^='ref_empl_']").each(function (index, el) {
    $(el).kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "/Total/StartService/Test"
            },
        },

    });
});
```

Comment: Почему тогда не получить 1 раз ваши данные и присвоить их напрямую без датабайдинга? Насколько я вижу это обычный словарь

Answer (score 0):

Порядок имеет значение. Поэтому разместите ваш код в documentReady обработчике, в самом конце страницы. И да проверьте путь, вдруг пропустили какой нибудь tbody

Comment: Если заполнять вот так то все работает (значит селектор работает правильно) dataSource: [
                            { text: "Cotton", value: "1" },
                            { text: "Polyester", value: "2" },
                            { text: "Cotton/Polyester", value: "3" },
                            { text: "Rib Knit", value: "4" }
                        ],